# Any good free VPN windows apps?

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I tried many free vpn like hotspot shield, urban vpn, express vpn none want to connect. I am in latest windows 11 version. Is there something that can work on Windows 11 ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't a real "app" but if that will work for you I would recommend using Opera, which offers free VPN. Besides, I'm already on Mozilla VPN's waiting list. This is my preference to use VPN as I don't find the free ones reliable.